# Uncaught type error cannot read property 'innerText' of null coffeescript ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I just started learning ruby on rails, and I am writing code snippets to learn how the CoffeeScript works. I know how javascript works so I tried to get the text of the button in CoffeeScript. However each time it says that cannot read property innerText of null. I have written the code. Any idea why this is? I am using Rails 5.2.0.

Coffeescript:

```
console.log "Hello" //this works

console.log document.getElementById("user_login_submission").innerText //this gives error
```

myproject.html.erb:

```
   `<button class="user_login_submission" id="user_login_submission">login</button>`
```

Comment: Can you see a button with `id` _"user_login_submission"_ when you check browser console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
<%= button_tag "Login", class:"user_login_submission", id:"user_login_submission" %>
```

Then make sure you include your coffee script in your app tree

Comment: Can you please explain the answer: I didn't understand is the button_tag to be written in html.erb file? (It doesn't look like html code)

Comment: Coffee Script is included in the app tree under javascripts folder.

Comment: Also I did what you said and the html doesn't recognize it anymore meaning it just displayed the whole line without showing the button. :(

Comment: please check the updated code .. this makes it work with erb files

Comment: I got this after adding the above statement in html.erb file
syntax error, unexpected '=' ...nd=( button_tag "Login", class="user_login_submission", id="... ... ^

Comment: Sorry. I have changed = to :

Comment: Is it possible to use the html tags like in normal web-pages? My html script contains html button tag.

Comment: I have added the html tag so that it is understandable

Comment: yes your statement is working and it shows a button. I have solved the problem/the problem was that I didn't use webapps while creating the rails project hence couldn't use jquery as after rails 5 jquery is not shipped along with it you have to add it separately while creating the project.